# Arranging data and making dictionary

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a tab delimited file that looks like this:

```
chr14   106559873       106560782       MA0004.1_Arnt
chr14   106559873       106560782       MA0093.1_USF1
chr14   106559873       106560782       MA0147.1_Myc
chr14   106559873       106560782       RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN
chr10   17037867        17038971        MA0080.2_SPI1
chr10   17037867        17038971        MA0152.1_NFATC2
chr17   8610947 8611433 MA0080.2_SPI1
chr17   8610947 8611433 MA0098.1_ETS1
```

i want to arrange it like this:

```
Regions   MA0004.1_Arnt  MA0093.1_USF1  MA0147.1_Myc  RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN MA0080.2_SPI1 MA0152.1_NFATC2 MA0098.1_ETS1
chr14;106559873;106560782   1 1 1 1 0 0 0
chr10;17037867;17038971     0 0 0 0 1 1 0
chr10;17037867;17038971     0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

the example output shows only for firs four lines, but this needs to be applied to whole of the file. 1 denotes the presence of the string.

Snce this is middle section of the code that i am writing it is crucial to my analysis. i cannot think anymore how to do this in awk.

thank you.

Comment: 1 indicates the presence or absence of string, like in the region chr14 106559873 106560782 has MA0004.1_Arnt. hence 1.

Comment: if present then 1 else 0.

Comment: You have to read the whole file to start printing...Even if it's doable, awk doesn't seem to be the practical choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk script gets you most of the way there:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Regions   MA0004.1_Arnt  MA0093.1_USF1  MA0147.1_Myc  RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN MA0080.2_SPI1 MA0152.1_NFATC2 MA0098.1_ETS1"
    a["MA0004.1_Arnt"] = a["MA0093.1_USF1"] = \
    a["MA0147.1_Myc"] = a["RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN"] = \
    a["MA0080.2_SPI1"] = a["MA0152.1_NFATC2"] = a["MA0098.1_ETS1"] = 0
}

function print_fields () {
    print p";"s";"e, a["MA0004.1_Arnt"], a["MA0093.1_USF1"],
    a["MA0147.1_Myc"], a["RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN"],
    a["MA0080.2_SPI1"], a["MA0152.1_NFATC2"], a["MA0098.1_ETS1"]    
}

NR>1&&$1!=p {
    print_fields()
    for (i in a) a[i] = 0
}

{ p=$1; s=$2; e=$3; a[$4]=1 }

END { print_fields() }
```

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Regions   MA0004.1_Arnt  MA0093.1_USF1  MA0147.1_Myc  RUNX3_DBD_WAACCRCAAWAACCRCAN MA0080.2_SPI1 MA0152.1_NFATC2 MA0098.1_ETS1
chr14;106559873;106560782 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
chr10;17037867;17038971 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
chr17;8610947;8611433 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Is the output tab seperated?

Comment: No, where should the tab be?

Comment: Try adding `OFS="\t"` to the `BEGIN` block, does that produce the desired output?